# merge function in kaggel

Tags: r, r-markdown, kaggle

I have a problem with the function `merge` in kaggel. When I run it in RStudio it works but not in kaggel.

I have two different tables with the sames colomnes: "Id" and "ActivityDay".

I want to merge the two table in one by "Id" AND "ActivityDay"

*my code:*

```
daily_Calories_Steps <- merge(daily_calories, dailySteps_merged, by = c("Id","ActivityDay"))
```

*warning message:*

Error in fix.by(by.x, x): 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column
Traceback:

1. merge(daily_calories, dailySteps_merged, by = c("Id", "ActivityDay"))
2. merge.data.frame(daily_calories, dailySteps_merged, by = c("Id",
   .     "ActivityDay"))
3. fix.by(by.x, x)
4. stop(ngettext(sum(bad), "'by' must specify a uniquely valid column",
   .     "'by' must specify uniquely valid columns"), domain = NA)

Thanks for helping...

I want to make a notebook in kaggel but this code doesnt work...